# How to replace a specific sequence of numbers (per row) with another sequence in a big data frame in R?

Tags: r, replace, data.table, sequence, gaps-in-data

I have a data.frame with absence/presence data (0/1) for a group of animals, with columns as years and rows as individuals.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(Year1 = c('1','0','0','0','0','0'),
                 Year2 = c('1','1','1','0','0','0'),
                 Year3 = c('1','1','1','1','1','0'),
                 Year4 = c('0','1','0','0','0','1'),
                 Year5 = c('0','0','1','1','0','1'),
                 Year6 = c('0','0','0','1','1','1'))

df
     Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6
1:     1     1     1     0     0     0
2:     0     1     1     1     0     0
3:     0     1     1     0     1     0
4:     0     0     1     0     1     1
5:     0     0     1     0     0     1
6:     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

Some individuals have sighting gaps (seen one year (1), then not seen the next year (0), but spotted again in the third year (1)). In total there are 400 rows (=individuals).

What I would like to do is fill the gaps (0s between 1s) with 1s, so that the above data frame becomes:

```
df
     Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6
1:     1     1     1     0     0     0
2:     0     1     1     1     0     0
3:     0     1     1     1     1     0
4:     0     0     1     1     1     1
5:     0     0     1     1     1     1
6:     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

Zeros before the first 1 and after the last 1 should not be affected.

I have browsed many *stackoverflow* questions, e.g.:

[find and replace numeric sequence in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067073/find-and-replace-numeric-sequence-in-r)

[Replace a sequence of values by group depending on preceeding values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287065/replace-a-sequence-of-values-by-group-depending-on-preceeding-values)

However, I could not find a solution that works across all columns at once, on a row-by-row basis.

Thank you in advance for your advice! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do this by row.  An efficient option is using `dapply` from `collapse`.  Loop over the rows, find the position index of 1s, get the sequence between the first and last, and `replace` those elements to 1.

```
library(collapse)
dapply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)
     replace(x,  do.call(`:`, as.list(range(which(x == 1)))),  1 ))
```

-output

```
  Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6
1     1     1     1     0     0     0
2     0     1     1     1     0     0
3     0     1     1     1     1     0
4     0     0     1     1     1     1
5     0     0     1     1     1     1
6     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

---

An option is also to get the row/column index with `which` and `arr.ind = TRUE`, then create the sequence, and use the row/column index to do the assignment which is vectorized

```
ind <- which(df ==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
m1 <- as.matrix(transform(stack(lapply(split(ind[,2], ind[,1]), 
   function(x) x[1]:x[length(x)]))[2:1], ind = as.integer(ind)))
df[m1] <- 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `max.col` to find the "first" and "last" `1` in each row, and then compare to the `col()`umn number:

```
df[col(df) >= max.col(df, "first") & col(df) <= max.col(df, "last")] <- 1
df

#  Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6
#1     1     1     1     0     0     0
#2     0     1     1     1     0     0
#3     0     1     1     1     1     0
#4     0     0     1     1     1     1
#5     0     0     1     1     1     1
#6     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach in base R using `apply` -

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  rg <- range(which(x == 1))
  x[rg[1]:rg[2]] <- 1
  x
}))

df

#  Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6
#1     1     1     1     0     0     0
#2     0     1     1     1     0     0
#3     0     1     1     1     1     0
#4     0     0     1     1     1     1
#5     0     0     1     1     1     1
#6     0     0     0     1     1     1
```